# How to get all sharepoint site feature's names and id

Tags: sharepoint, guid

I have been trying to use $features = Get-PnPFeature and $features = Get-PnPFeature -Scope Site But I only get the enabled features and it doesn't include all the features. I need a complete list of names and ids so I can use the ids to customize a template.

```
$features = Get-PnPFeature 

 foreach ($feature in $features) {
    Write-Host "Feature Name: $($feature.DisplayName)"
    Write-Host "Feature ID: $($feature.DefinitionId)"
    Write-Host "-----------------------"
}
```

Comment: ChatGPT generated a list for me. In case it helps anyone else, the link to the list is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vngYALYHlkA801Vd4y6vOi5wONFKGN6JWr6_ujTbzbU/edit?usp=sharing

I still need to find a way to get all features, but that helps.

Comment: You can check this site https://sharepointtechnicalsupport.com/sharepoint-2019-feature-id-feature-using-powershell/ maybe it helps. What's the version of your SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following powershell script to get all features

```
#Variables
$SiteURL="https://Crescent.sharepoint.com"
 
#Setup Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
 
#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
 
#Get Site Collection Features
$SiteCollFeatures = $Ctx.Site.Features
$Ctx.Load($SiteCollFeatures)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()           
 
#Loop through each feature and get feature data
Write-host "Site Collection Features:"
ForEach($Feature in $SiteCollFeatures)
{
    $Feature.Retrieve("DisplayName")
    $Ctx.Load($Feature)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $Feature | Select DisplayName, DefinitionId
}
```